# Selecting a particular row from database which has multiple tables

Tags: mysql, database, rows

I have a database called "SHOP_DETAILS" which has 30 tables like Apolo,Gov,...etc and each table has 100 more records. Now I want to search for a particular record from all the table in single command. Suggest me a way to achieve the task.

I am using MySql database using XAMPP.

For Example:

```
Apolo table

name stock price    
----|-----|------
a   |  20 |    5
b   |   2 |    4
c   |  24 |   54
d   |  47 |   19
r   |  47 |   19
f   |   7 |   12
g   |   5 |    5

Apolo12 table
name stock price
----|-----|------
fg  |  20 |    5
f   |   2 |    4
r   |  24 |   54
u   |  47 |   19
r   |  47 |   19
i   |   7 |   12
u   |   5 |    5

GOv table
name stock price
----|-----|------
l   |  20 |    5
p   |   2 |    4
v   |  24 |   54
k   |  47 |   19
u   |  47 |   19
r   |   7 |   12
g   |   5 |    5

KAv table
name stock price
----|-----|------
k   |  20 |    5
b   |   2 |    4
n   |  24 |   54
d   |  47 |   19
k   |  47 |   19
f   |   7 |   12
t   |   5 |    5
```

Like these there are many tables with different values.

Now I have a text box in my page in which a name is specified, then with the name given in the textbox I have to search for all the tables in the database and return which tables contains the given input name.

Please provide me the solution  to this.

Comment: define  particular record

Comment: This kind of problem is often symptomatic of poor design.

Comment: @Strawberry .. How to get result with this poor design

Comment: Fix the design ;-)

Comment: @Strawberry.... How to fix or Suggest me a perfect design to my requirement

Answer (score 0):

If you want answer for this poor design only, then see the following:-

```
select * from Apolo a, Apolo12 a1, ... where a.name='your_wish' or a1.name='your_widh' or .....;
```

Comment: I am having more than 30 tables.. How can I type entire table name in my query

Comment: Then you have to improve your design.

Answer (score 0):

An example of an improved design *might* be as follows, with a PK formed on (shop,name)...

```
stocks_table

shop    | name | stock | price 
--------+------+-------+------
apolo   | a    |    20 |     5
apolo   | b    |     2 |     4
apolo   | c    |    24 |    54
apolo   | d    |    47 |    19
apolo   | r    |    47 |    19
apolo   | f    |     7 |    12
apolo   | g    |     5 |     5
Apolo12 | fg   |    20 |     5
Apolo12 | f    |     2 |     4
Apolo12 | r    |    24 |    54
Apolo12 | u    |    47 |    19
Apolo12 | r    |    47 |    19
Apolo12 | i    |     7 |    12
Apolo12 | u    |     5 |     5
GOv     | l    |    20 |     5
GOv     | p    |     2 |     4
GOv     | v    |    24 |    54
GOv     | k    |    47 |    19
GOv     | u    |    47 |    19
GOv     | r    |     7 |    12
GOv     | g    |     5 |     5
KAv     | k    |    20 |     5
KAv     | b    |     2 |     4
KAv     | n    |    24 |    54
KAv     | d    |    47 |    19
KAv     | k    |    47 |    19
KAv     | f    |     7 |    12
KAv     | t    |     5 |     5
```